# How to read a char/string as hex?

Tags: c#

The user is entering a frequency in a text box, which I am reading as a string.
The frequency is then converted to its hex equivalent.
Now I want to read the last two elements of freqhex and concatenate them and store as byte.
For ex. if the user enters frequency 282.000 MHz. FreqHex will store 00044D90. I want to read "90" and store as byte. SS_Buf[15] should store 90 as byte.

```
string frequency = freq_box.Text;
byte[] SS_Buf = new byte[117];
string FreqHex = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(frequency), 16);
SS_Buf[15] = byte (FreqHex[6]+FreqHex[7]); // trying to store as byte, it's not correct
```

Hi, Actually the full code is like this:

```
string frequency = freq_box.Text;
        string[] strArr = null;
        strArr = frequency.Split('.');
        string FreqHex = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(strArr[0]+strArr[1]), 16);
        while(FreqHex.Length<8)
        {
            FreqHex = "0"+FreqHex;

        }
```

SS_Buf[15] = (byte)(FreqHex[6]+FreqHex[7]);

The user will enter freq like this xxx.xxx
I want to use xxxxxx for converting to hex. If the number of bits are less than 8, I will append 0's in front. 
It's like hex signed 2nd compliment.
So, I was thinking if I could use 'FreqHex' instead of 'frequency' to store value in SS_Buf[15]
. If the hex value is 00044D90: 
SS_Buf[15] should be 90,   SS_Buf[14] should be 4D,    SS_Buf[13] should be 04, 
   SS_Buf[12] should be 00

Answer (score 4):

There is actually no need to convert to hex. You just need a bit of masking. Note that everything is represented in binary, though it might not seem like it.

To get the last two hex digits is basically getting the last rightmost 8 bits. To do this, you apply a mask of `0xff` (`1111 1111` in binary) and use the bitwise AND operator:

```
SS_Buf[15] = (byte)(Convert.ToInt32(frequency) & 0xff)
```

If `frequency` were 44D90 in hex, it would be

```
0100 0100 1101 1001 0000
```

in binary

Now we apply a mask of `0xff`, which is

```
0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

Now if we do a bitwise AND operation, we get:

```
0000 0000 0000 1001 0000
```

Comment: hi, actually the full code is like this: string frequency = freq_box.Text;
            string[] strArr = null;
            strArr = frequency.Split('.');
            string FreqHex = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(strArr[0]+strArr[1]), 16);
            while(FreqHex.Length<8)
            {
                FreqHex = "0"+FreqHex;

            }

Comment: @JyotiYadav You don't need the while loop. Just do `(byte)(Convert.ToInt32(strArrr[0] + strArr[1]) & 0xff)`

Comment: More generally, the bitwise and (`&`) can be thought of as a 'save these bits' operator. In the case of `x = x&y`, also written as `x&=y` , each bit of y that is set to 1, will preserve the value of the corresponding bit in x, whether 1 or 0. All other bits of x will be set to 0. As @Sweeper demonstrates, this operator is a very effective way at isolating sections of a bit sequence, by preserving a sub-sequence, and nullifying the rest.

Comment: @Sweeper I am getting error "Input string was not in a correct format." when trying to use SS_Buf[15] = (byte)(Convert.ToInt32(frequency) & 0xff)

Comment: @JyotiYadav no don’t use `frequency`, replace it with `strArr[0] + strArr[1]`

Comment: @Sweeper it's working ..i did like this SS_Buf[15] = (byte)(Convert.ToInt32(strArr[0] + strArr[1]) & 0x000000ff); Now, what to do if i want to read "4D" "04" and "00" as well

Comment: @JyotiYadav that’s another question. You shift the whole bit pattern to the right 8 times first, then apply the same mask, and you will get 4D.